# Why bi-directional mapping does not take value from both sides of the relationship?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So, lets take I have two entity :

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
//@ToString(exclude = "courseMaterial")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "course_sequence", sequenceName = "course_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "course_sequence")
    private Long courseId;
    private String title;
    private Integer credit;

    //bidirectional mapping
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private CourseMaterial courseMaterial;

}
```

and

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
//@ToString(exclude = "course")
public class CourseMaterial {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "course_material_sequence", sequenceName = "course_material_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "course_material_sequence")
    private Long courseMaterialId;
    private String url;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "courseId")
    private Course course;

}
```

Tests

```java
@SpringBootTest
class CourseMaterialRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private CourseMaterialRepository courseMaterialRepository;

    @Test
    public void saveCourseMaterial() {

        Course course = Course.builder()
                        .title(".net-2")
                        .credit(7)
                        .build();

        CourseMaterial courseMaterial = CourseMaterial.builder()
                        .url("www.dotnet.com")
                        .course(course)
                        .build();

        courseMaterialRepository.save(courseMaterial);
    }

    @Test
    public void printAllCourseMaterials() {
        List<CourseMaterial> courseMaterials =
                courseMaterialRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println("courseMaterials = " + courseMaterials);
    }

}
```

and

```java
@SpringBootTest
class CourseRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    CourseRepository courseRepository;

    @Test
    public void saveCourse() {

        CourseMaterial courseMaterial = CourseMaterial.builder()
                .url("www.codejava.com")
                .build();

        Course course = Course.builder()
                .title("JAVA")
                .credit(6)
                .courseMaterial(courseMaterial)
                .build();

        courseRepository.save(course);
    }

    @Test
    public void printCourses() {
        List<Course> courses = courseRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println("courses = " + courses);
    }
}
```

So here, when I am saving data from `CourseMaterialRepositoryTest.saveCourseMaterial()` method `courseId` is saved in `course_material` table.
But when I am saving from `CourseRepositoryTest.saveCourse()` method `courseId` is not saved in `course_material` table.

Please help me solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how relationship works with JPA.
The `mappedBy` attribute in

```java
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private CourseMaterial courseMaterial;
```

Declares that the relationship is controlled by `Coursematerial.course` and it is the only value that matters when the relation gets persisted.
The other side only reads the matching data when loaded from the database.
When not loading data from the database you have to make sure both sides are consistent.